# Banco de dados local (serveless) não modificável com atualização

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Cenário:

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno aplicativo `WinForm` em `C#` para distribuir para vendedores montarem seus orçamentos mais rapidamente e gostaria de armazenar informações simples, tais como orçamento emitidos e clientes cadastrados.

Pois bem, até hoje desenvolvi apenas trabalhando com `SQL Server`, mas nesse projeto gostaria de instalar, juntamente com a distribuição do aplicativo, um Banco de Dados local em cada cliente que não seja afetado caso a aplicação seja atualizada.

Procurei algumas opções de "small DB", tais como `SQLite`, mas, pelo que entendi, o arquivo com os registros é distribuído juntamente com a aplicação e minha preocupação é em não perder os dados já salvos em cada PC.

Há alguma forma padrão de lidar com isso?

Minha dúvida é no momento de atualização do aplicativo: se o banco de dados é distribuído juntamente com a aplicação, logo ele será substituído numa possível atualização, correto (ou não?). É esse problema que não sei como lidar e gostaria de contornar.

Como trabalhar utilizando e armazenando registros em Bancos de Dados locais para cada cliente, sem que haja `substituição` desses Banco numa atualização do aplicativo?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "não perder os dados já salvos em cada PC"?

Comment: Quero dizer que, na minha cabeça, ao atualizar uma aplicação que utiliza dados locais, os arquivos onde os registros são armazenados também serão substituídos, correto? Ou não? Essa perda de dados que quero evitar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas deixando meus 2 centavos, existe o modo portátil do SQL Server chamado [LocalDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh510202(v=sql.120).aspx). Você não precisa instalar o SQL Server inteiro na máquina do usuário: apenas o adaptador cliente e o arquivo MDF que representa o banco.

Além disso, se por um acaso você escolher o [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) como *framework* de abstração do seu banco de dados, você pode fazer as atualizações de dados usando o mecanismo de [*Migrations*](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). O banco de dados não é substituído: é automaticamente atualizado de acordo com as variações produzidas no seu código ao desenvolver a aplicação.

Comment: Ótima referência. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Quando você deixa os dados no cliente, sempre terá o risco de perdê-los, não há nada que possa ser feito. O arquivo pode ser apagado acidentalmente pelo usuário ou vírus, mal funcionamento do equipamento, etc. Na verdade é o mesmo risco do servidor, a diferença é que este costuma ter mais restrição de acesso, não é manipulado por leigos (na prática até costuma ser :) ) e há estratégias boas de *backup* (nem sempre :) ).

O que pode ser feito é uma estratégia de sincronização do banco de dados local com uma cópia no servidor. Pode até mesmo usar instâncias do SQLite no servidor para armazenar o banco de cada vendedor.

A cliente irá identificar sempre que ele tiver acesso ao servidor e iniciará o sincronismo. Ele também identificará se o servidor pode estar mais atualizado e sincronizar de forma inversa. Isto pode ser útil também se o vendedor utilizar mais de um dispositivo.

O servidor terá um serviço que fará a comunicação com o cliente e gravar as atualizações na cópia do servidor. Ou enviará para o cliente os dados atualizados quando o servidor estiver mais atual.

Os detalhes de como fazer isto, estratégias para detectar a desatualização mais facilmente não caberia aqui. Eventualmente pode-se fazer a cópia do arquivo todo sempre, só se baseando no horário dele. Não é o mais eficiente e robusto, mas funciona em quase todos casos.

Claro que sempre existe estratégias mais simples como fazer mais cópias locais, obrigar o usuário fazer algo manualmente, etc.

## Sobre a atualização do aplicativo

Se é atualização, ele não deve ser copiado. Simples assim.

E se acontecer uma sobreposição por acidente, só a estratégia descrita acima vai resolver.

Se a estrutura do banco de dados mudou, tem que existir um rotina que faça a mudança. O `ALTER TABLE` do SQLite é fraco. Tem que criar uma tabela nova, copiar os dados existentes na tabela antiga para a nova, tratando as diferenças da estrutura antiga para a nova. Depois apaga a antiga e renomeia a nova.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição @bigown, mas na verdade, sobre essa parte de sincronização e backup, até já tenho uma estratégia em mente para lidar com isso. Minha pergunta é focada na questão do momento de atualização do aplicativo: se o banco de dados é distribuído juntamente com a aplicação, logo ele será substituído numa possível atualização, correto (ou não?). É esse problema que não sei como lidar e gostaria de contornar.

Comment: Ninguém está entendo o que você quer. Você tem que explicar melhor. Pra mim, a perda só pode ocorrer nessa situação que eu descrevi. Se pode haver perda em outro momento, você tem que dizer o que está fazendo e porque pode haver perda. Talvez só deva parar de fazer o que pode provocar a perda.

Comment: Justo. Na verdade é um problema puramente teórico e conceitual. Não é que eu `esteja` fazendo algo errado, eu simplesmente `não sei` como fazer. Pontuando: como trabalho com um banco de dados local para cada cliente. Entende?

Comment: Eu tentei melhorar, mas desde seu primeiro comentário e as edições, você está sendo quase redundante nas informações sem colocar esclarecimentos reais. frases como "como trabalho com um banco de dados local para cada cliente" não diz nada sobre o que precisa, qual seu problema. Ou seja, a pergunta fica muito ampla. Eu respondi o que dá com o que foi escrito. Se precisa de algo mais específico, vai ter que especificar.

Comment: Ok, já me ajudou em alguns pontos. É complicado perguntar algo quando não se sabe quais são as possibilidades disponíveis. Mas obrigado.

Comment: As possibilidades eu já coloquei. Se tem um problema mais específico, tem que especificar. Quando você coloca a pergunta genérica, e não tem problema inerente nisto, vai receber uma resposta genérica. Quando você for lidar com o problema real,m você pode postar uma pergunta mostrando ele e perguntando como resolver a situação.

Comment: A ideia de montar um servidor de sincronia de dados é bem legal. Poderia até ser oferecida como serviço adicional juntamente com o produto. +1.